# Compiler cannot deduce the specialised template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction

I have the following code in a class

```
  struct ConstrType{};
  struct ConstrType3{};
  struct ConstrType2{};
  struct ConstrType1{};

  template<typename InType, typename OutType, typename ConstrType>
  class getInterestRateIndex_impl{
  public:
    getInterestRateIndex_impl(){
      std::cout << "Generic getInterestedRateIndex_impl instantiated. Failed" << std::endl;
//      BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(ConstrType) == 0);
    }
    boost::shared_ptr<OutType> operator()() const{
      return boost::shared_ptr<OutType>();
    }
  };


  template<typename InType, typename OutType>
  class getInterestRateIndex_impl<InType, OutType, ConstrType2>{
  public:
    getInterestRateIndex_impl(){
      std::cout << "ConstrType2 getInterestedRateIndex_impl instantiated." << std::endl;
    }
    boost::shared_ptr<OutType> operator()() const{
      return boost::shared_ptr<OutType>();
    }
  };


  template<typename InType, typename OutType>
  class getInterestRateIndex_impl<InType, OutType, ConstrType1>{
  public:
    getInterestRateIndex_impl(){
      std::cout << "ConstrType1 getInterestedRateIndex_impl instantiated." << std::endl;
    }
    boost::shared_ptr<OutType> operator()() const{
      return boost::shared_ptr<OutType>();
    }
  };



  template<typename InType, typename OutType>
  boost::shared_ptr<OutType> getInterestRateIndex() const{
//    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_base_of<OutType, InType>::value);

    typedef typename
      boost::mpl::if_
      <
          boost::is_same<InType, QuantLib::Libor>,
          QuantLib::Libor,
          boost::mpl::if_
          <
              boost::mpl::or_
              <
                  boost::mpl::or_
                  <
                      boost::is_same<InType, QuantLib::Euribor>,
                      boost::is_same<InType, QuantLib::EURLibor>,
                      boost::is_base_of<QuantLib::Libor, InType>
                  >
              >,
              ConstrType2,
              boost::mpl::if_
              <
                  boost::mpl::or_
                  <
                      boost::is_base_of<QuantLib::Euribor, InType>,
                      boost::is_base_of<QuantLib::EURLibor, InType>
                  >,
                  ConstrType1,
                  ConstrType
              > 
          > 
      >::type Type;
//    std::cout << typeid(Type).name() << std::endl;
//    throw std::exception(typeid(Type).name());

    return getInterestRateIndex_impl<InType, OutType, Type>()( );

  }
```

When I instantiate the class and invoke `getInterestRateIndex<DerivedFromLiborType, BaseType>()`, the compiler cannot choose the specialisation. When I uncomment the `exception` line, it can though detect that the `Type` after `typedef` is `ConstrType2`. Am I missing anything that can hint the compiler to choose the right specialisation?

PS: the template logic suppose to do something like .....

```
if(T is Libor)
    return LiborType
if(
   or(
      or(T = Euribor,
         T = EURLibor),
      is_base_of(T, Libor)
    ),
    ConstrType2,
    if( 
        or(is_base_of(T, Euribor),
           is_base_of(T, EURLibor)),
       ConstrType1,
       ConstrType
      )
   )
```

I do this because I need to dispatch `shared_ptr` based on the input type, and the desired underlying type in the shared_ptr wrapper.

Comment: Is the compiler emitting an error? or is it just choosing the wrong specialisation?

Comment: @zdan. MSVC compiles it and choose the default template class.

Comment: Eyes bleeding.  Can you boil this down a bit?

Comment: When I just replace your mpl logic with a hardcode typedef (i.e. typedef ConstrType2 Type;). It works for me. Can you try doing that and see what happens?

Comment: @zdan It can deduce to use the specialisation. The things is that at the exception, the type can be deduced to `ConstrType2` and display the right `typename`. This is why I think it is a compiler bug.... I am going to try this with gcc and clang++ and see what they get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the outer if statement cannot deduce the type of the "then" branch and return a compounded type of boost structs and therefore always choosing the full unspecialised template

Answer (score 1):

First, what John Dibling said in a comment: please try to boil this down a bit.  What would be ideal is to see something that *does* work alongside something similar that *doesn't*.

Just a guess, but by comparing with what you are intending to do via your pseudocode, it looks like you have messed up a couple of `boost::mpl::or_` calls.  Maybe

```
          boost::mpl::or_
          <
              boost::mpl::or_
              <
                  boost::is_same<InType, QuantLib::Euribor>,
                  boost::is_same<InType, QuantLib::EURLibor>,
                  boost::is_base_of<QuantLib::Libor, InType>
              >
          >,
```

should be

```
          boost::mpl::or_
          <
              boost::mpl::or_
              <
                  boost::is_same<InType, QuantLib::Euribor>,
                  boost::is_same<InType, QuantLib::EURLibor>
              >,
              boost::is_base_of<QuantLib::Libor, InType>
          >,
```

At present you have what looks like 1 1-operand `or_` and 1 3-operand `or_`.  According to the [Boost MPL docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/or.html), `or_` requires at least 2 operands, so perhaps your 1-operand `or_`, which I take to invoke Undefined Behaviour, is wrecking things.  (I'm surprised it compiles.)

Comment: Good catch but that was not the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You first define `struct ConstrType{};`
 and then you reuse ConstrType as a template parameter here `template<typename InType, typename OutType, typename ConstrType>
  class getInterestRateIndex_impl{`
 ?? ... That's asking for trouble. I'd rename one of them.